# How to create fade in fade out effect for a rectangle in Processing

Tags: processing

I'm trying to make fade in fade out effect in Processing. When I press the key 'z', the transparency of the rectangle go from 0 to 255, stay there for 1 sec then fade out from 255 to 0. Thank you in advance!

Here is one of my latest attempt:

```java
int alphaValue; 

void setup() { 
size(640, 360);
rect1 = createShape(RECT,292, 85, 55, 55, 2); 
rect2 = createShape(RECT,347, 140, 55, 55, 2); 
rect1.setFill(0); 
rect1.setStroke(color(255)); 
rect2.setFill(0); 
rect2.setStroke(color(255)); 
}

void keyPressed() {

    if (key == 'z')
    {
      fadingrectangle();

    }
}
void fadingrectangle() { 
rect1.setFill(color(229, 229, 229, alphaValue));

if (alphaValue < 255) { 
alphaValue++; 
} 
}
```

I just can make it fading in but I don't know how to make it automatically fading out after appearing 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense.

First off, you need to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program). For example, can you create a simple program that just shows a rectangle? Can you create a separate program that just prints something to the console when the user presses the Z key? Get those working perfectly by themselves before you move on.

From there, you need to store the current **state** of your sketch. In your case, maybe that's a single variable that stores the transparency of the rectangle. Then you need to use that variable to draw each frame, and change that variable to make the rectangle fade in and out. [Here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation) is a tutorial I wrote about animation in Processing.

But again, you need to break your problem down into smaller pieces. Approach each piece by itself, and post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific technical question if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Before posting this, I've tried several ways but they weren't really working. This example [link] (https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/mousepressed-fade-in-fade-out.html) is the closest one to mine but in this, user needs to release the mouse to create fading out effect. In my case, I'd like it to be automatically fade out after fading in 1 sec. So this is one of my latest attempt:

Comment: I've added my code in the description. Please scroll up to review it. Thank you so much.